# Crack in foundation, what to do?

Tags: basement, foundation, crack, cement

I noticed a crack in the basement wall above ground next to the basement window. The crack goes all the way through the wall and is visible both inside and outside of the house. I have attached two pictures:

[image]

How big of an issue is this? Is this something that I can fix myself?

Comment: Odd shape crack, almost like someone drove into the wall.  Can you post some more pictures showing more of the wall/window?

Comment: @crip659 This wall is the wall facing my neighbor's house in the area between our houses, so it's not from anything like a car hitting it.

Comment: Plain vanilla foundation crack.  Nothing to worry about unless it grows.

Comment: Age of house will be useful, most foundations warranted for about five years.

Comment: @HotLicks What is typically done to fix this type of crack?

Comment: @crip659 The house is 20 years old

Comment: Just caulk it..

Comment: @Ruskes But what about the picture on the right, isn't that concrete or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Ruskes Does that change what I use to fix it? What type of caulking or cement should I use?